# Change icon depending on language in Qt

Tags: qt

Is there a standard mechanism for setting language-depending icons in Qt.
If not, would this work and would it be safe:

```
MyWidget->setIcon(QPixmap(dir.currentPath() + tr("/images/icon_en.png") ));
//icon_en should be translated according to corresponding image names
```

Comment: you can get language from QtLocale, then convert it to a string with `languageToString`. in your resoucrce file/directory, create a folder for each language, and fill with the appropriate icons. use the langauge string to find the proper path.http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlocale.html#language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard mechanism for setting icon depending on the locale in Qt. Nevertheless, writing your own mechanism is very plain.

IMO, using `tr` in your code is redundant. This way is much more flexible:

```
// Get current system locale:
const QString LOCALE = QLocale::system().name(); // For example, result is "en_US"

// Extract language code from the previously obtained locale:
const QString LANG = LOCALE.split('_').at(0);    // Result is "en"

// Path to our icons:
const QString PATH = QString(QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/images");

// Build the path to the icon file:
const QString ICON = QString("%1/icon_%2.png").arg(PATH, LANG);

// Check if the icon for the current locale exists:
if (QFile::exists(ICON)) {
    // Set this icon for our window:
    setWindowIcon(QPixmap(ICON));
}
else {
    // Otherwise fallback to the default icon:
    setWindowIcon(QPixmap(PATH + "/icon_default.png"));
}
```

Generally, the technique you posted is correct. Just few remarks on your code:

- Note that [`QDir::currentPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#currentPath) does **not** return the executable directory; it returns the current working directory. Use [`QApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) instead.
- You may also want to use [Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) instead of storing images along with your executable.

Comment: Thank, however, this seems to be more complicated and less flexible than using tr. With tr-method I could e.g. assign one icon to a group of languages. Все равно спасибо ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can load an icon from a ressource file.

Then you can specify an alias for specific languages in the ressource file:

```
<qresource>
    <file>cut.jpg</file>
</qresource>
<qresource lang="fr">
    <file alias="cur.jpg">cut_fr.jpg</file>
<qresource>
```

This way when the app is turned to french automatically the alias icon is selected.